# Which is the best English term for "the result of a mathematical integration"?

Tags: integration, terminology, article-writing

I am writing an academic paper. And I wonder which is the best English term for "the result of a mathematical integration".

For example, I have a mathematical integration as below.

$$F = \int f(u) du$$

Which is a more suitable name for $F$? "integral $f(u)$" or "integrated $f(u)$"? I must name $F$ in a way expressing its relationship with $f(u)$.

---

Thanks for your comments! As it is the "integral of $f(u)$", can I name it "integral $f(u)$" for short? I think I have to omit the preposition when defining a new academic word. ($f(u)$ is an already-defined physical term.)

Comment: I would just say "$F$ is the integral of $f$" or "$F$ is an antiderivative of $f$."

Comment: An indefinite integral of or an antiderivative of.

Comment: It is 'integral **of** $f(u)$'

Comment: @YvesDaoust   Can I name it 'integral f(u)' for short? I think I have to omit the preposition when defining a new academic word. f(u) is an already defined physical term.

Comment: @tlsshhj: do you want to invent a name for a specific antiderivative ? Can we see it or is it terribly top secret ?

Comment: You could say, for example, that velocity is 'the integral of acceleration' or even that it is 'the integrated acceleration'. 'The integral acceleration' wouldn't sound right to me, though: 'integral' as an adjective usually refers to something being an *integer*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I want to invent a name. The mathematical integration described above summarizes  the relationship between those two terms. Assuming that () is a feature distribution function, I am not sure whether it is correct to call   'integral feature' or 'integrated feature'.

Comment: @JohnGowers Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately, my answer got ransom-hacked.

Comment: Personally, I would *vote* for Yves Daoust's first comment.  In fact, the term *antiderivative* connotes that the derivative function is being *inverted.*  Also, the term antiderivative is often used in connection with an indefinite integral.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with some comments.  The term "integral" is used both for the problem and for the answer.  This is like a lot of other words in mathematics:

> 5+3 is an easy sum
> What is 5+3? The sum is 8.

> 5! is the product of the numbers from 1 to 5
> 120 is the product of the numbers from 1 to 5

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\int f$ is generally used in one of two contexts:  either it represents a *number* (which we generally interpret as the area under the graph of $f$, but it is actually more general than that), or it represents a *function*.

#### A number

If $\int f$ represents a number, then it is a definite integral.  More commonly, this is written in the form
$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\int_E f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x.$$
Sometimes, a definite integral will be written without giving explicit bounds for the integration, or without specifying a domain of integration.  In such a context where a number is still meant, this notation is generally understood to indicate integration over the entire domain of the function.  For example,
$$ \int \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\pi}.$$
In this context, the number which is obtained by integration is called the **integral**.  More precisely, one might say that $\int_E f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is called the "**definite integral** of $f$ over $E$".

#### A function

The same notation is also used to denote a function.  For example, if $f$ is a "sufficiently nice" read-valued function defined on the real numbers, and there is a function $F$ with the property that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$, then we say that $F$ is an **antiderivative** or **primitive** of $f$.  This is often written as
$$ F(x) = \int_{a}^{t} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
F = \int f. $$
It should be noted that $F$ is not unique—a function may have *many* antiderivatives, though these antiderivatives differ by only a constant, so it is not hard to specify the entire family of antiderivatives.  The notation $\int f$ is, perhaps, confusing, but it is justified by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which demonstrates that definite integrals and antiderivatives are related, e.g. in the setting of Riemann integration, $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then
$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = F(b) - F(a). $$
This function might also be called the indefinite integral or inverse derivative. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) gives another couple of terms.

#### A note on notation

The notation $f$ denotes a function, while $f(u)$ or $f(x)$ denotes a *value* of that function—this latter notation represents a *number* (or dependent variable), not a function.  Thus it is a little strange to talk about "the integral of $f(u)$".  Thus it is fine to say that something is the "integral of $f$", but it is not quite right to say that it is the "integral of $f(u)$".

#### TL;DR

If $\int f$ denotes a number, that number is the **integral** or **definite integral** of $f$ (over some interval or domain).  If $\int f$ denotes a function, that function is an **antiderivative** or **primitive** of $f$.  In either case, I would not elide the preposition—keep that "of" in there.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This seems correct and explains a simple point that notation tends to obscure.  Spivak discusses this at length several times.